# How to initialize array with one non-zero value

Tags: rust

I'm creating a number type that uses arrays to store the numbers. To implement the trait `One`, I find myself writing code like this:

```rust
    fn one() -> Self {
        let mut ret_array = [0; N];
        ret_array[0] = 1;
        Self(ret_array)
    }
```

Is there an alternative way to initialize an array with *one* non-zero element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, no.

But the Rust compiler understands what you are trying to achieve and [optimizes it accordingly](https://godbolt.org/z/KGWeafb9d):

```rust
pub fn one<const N: usize>() -> [i32; N] {
    let mut ret_array = [0; N];
    ret_array[0] = 1;
    ret_array
}


pub fn one_with_length_5() -> [i32; 5] {
    one()
}
```

```
example::one_with_length_5:
        mov     rax, rdi
        xorps   xmm0, xmm0
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 4], xmm0
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], 1
        ret
```

- `xorps xmm0, xmm0` sets the 16-byte (or 4-int) SSE register `xmm0` to [0,0,0,0].
- `movups xmmword ptr [rdi + 4], xmm0` copies all 4 ints of the `xmm0` register to the location `[rdi + 4]`, which is the elements 1, 2, 3 and 4 of `ret_array`.
- `mov dword ptr [rdi], 1` moves the value `1` to the first element of the `ret_array`.
- `ret_array` is at the location of `[rdi]`, `[rdi + 4]` is the element at position `ret_array[1]`, `[rdi + 8]` is the element at position `ret_array[2]`, etc.

As you can see, it only initializes the other four values with 0, and then sets the first value to 1. The first value does not get written twice.

---

### Small remark

If you set `N` to e.g. `8`, it *does* actually write the value twice:

```
example::one_with_length_8:
        mov     rax, rdi
        xorps   xmm0, xmm0
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 16], xmm0
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 4], xmm0
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], 1
        ret
```

Interestingly, it doesn't actually write the value `[0]` twice, but the value `[4]`. It once writes `[1,2,3,4]`, and then `[4,5,6,7]`, then the one to `[0]`.
But that's because this is the fastest way to do it. It stores 4 ints of zeros in the SSE registers and then zero-initializes the vector 4 ints at a time. Writing an int twice is faster than initializing the other values without the help of 4-int SSE commands.

This would even happen if you initialized it completely manually:

```rust
pub fn one_with_length_8() -> [i32; 8] {
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
}
```

```
example::one_with_length_8:
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], 1
        xorps   xmm0, xmm0
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 4], xmm0
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 16], xmm0
        ret
```

You can see the order is different, but the instructions are identical.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you add a few comments to what each assembly instruction does? I think there is some boilerplate in the beginning, and `xorps xmm0 xmm0` sets a register to zero. So I'm specifically thinking about `movups xmmword ptr [rdi + 4], xmm0` and `mov     dword ptr [rdi], 1`.

Comment: Added a couple of explanations to the assembly code, hope it helps

Comment: Very nice. Thanks! I only have a rudimentary understanding of x86, so having the SSE extension instructions annotated is very helpful.